# Can't generate source with wsimport using Maven

Tags: java, web-services, maven, netbeans, wsimport

My Maven is pretty simple :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mavenproject4</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlUrls>
                                <wsdlUrl>
                                    http://localhost:8080/almexOffice/TarifWS?wsdl                                   
                                </wsdlUrl>
                            </wsdlUrls>
                            <packageName>com.mycompany
                            </packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>    

</project>
```

I want to create the generated source classes from a WSDL file. In my case it is at the location

```
http://localhost:8080/almexOffice/TarifWS?wsdl.
```

When i run an install/build then the output I get looks like this :

> --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mavenproject4 --- Deleting
>   C:\Users\lauren\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject4\target

```
> --- jaxws-maven-plugin:1.10:wsimport (default) @ mavenproject4 --- Processing: http://mylocalhosthere:8080/almexOffice/TarifWS?wsdl
> jaxws:wsimport args: [-s,
> C:\Users\lauren\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject4\target\jaxws\wsimport\java,
> -d, C:\Users\lauren\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject4\target\classes,
> -p, com.mycompany, http://mylocalhosthere:8080/almexOffice/TarifWS?wsdl] parsing WSDL...
```

> generating code...
>
> compiling code...
>
> Nothing to do, no WSDL found!
>
> --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ mavenproject4 --- [debug] execute contextualize Using 'UTF-8' encoding
>   to copy filtered resources. skip non existing resourceDirectory
>   C:\Users\lauren\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject4\src\main\resources

Now when i look in the source (target, generated-src) etc. I cannot find the generated classes.

Where are these generated files, and do they exist?

Comment: This wsdl (http://localhost:8080/almexOffice/TarifWS?wsdl) is available when source is generated?

Comment: yes ..................